# cannot figure out while random number generator game is not working c#

Tags: c#, random

I am programming a game that generates a random number and then has the user try to guess the number when the user inputs a number the program will respond with either too high or too low depending on the number generated.The problem I am having is that the loop will just keep executing and the program will not take another user input if the number is incorrect.I have tried using different types of loops like a do while and for loop but keep getting the same problem I feel as though I am missing something simple or making a simple mistake thanks

```
        string usernumber;

        Random rnd = new Random();

        int value = rnd.Next(1,50); //generates a random number upto 50

        int guess = 0;

        Console.WriteLine("please enter a number"); //asks for and takes user input

        usernumber = Console.ReadLine();//stores user input

        guess = Convert.ToInt32(usernumber);

        while (guess != value) //this stands for not equals to 
        {
            //guess = Convert.ToInt32(usernumber);

            if (value > guess)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("too high");
            }
            else if (value < guess)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("too low");
            }
            else if (value == guess)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("bang on the answer was" + value);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("errrrrrrrrr");
            }
        }   



        Thread.Sleep(2000); //delays the program closing for a bit
```

Comment: The loops should starts where you want to repeat. You want to repeat user input - move it inside the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this corrected and refactored to have more explicit variables names.

We add 1 to 50 because the `Random.Next` last parameter is the upper bound excluded.

We use a `do...while` loop to have a concise algorithm.

We use `int.TryParse` to get the `int` from the user. This method returns `false` and sets the value to `0` in case of conversion error instead of an exception.

We use `Console.ReadKey` instead of `Thread.Sleep`, that is more UX friendly.

```
var random = new Random();
int numberTarget = random.Next(1, 50 + 1);
int numberUser;
do
{
  Console.Write("Please enter a number between 1 and 50: ");
  if ( int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out numberUser) )
  {
    if ( numberUser > numberTarget )
    {
      Console.WriteLine("Too high, retry.");
    }
    else 
    if ( numberUser < numberTarget )
    {
      Console.WriteLine("Too low, retry.");
    }
    else
    {
      Console.WriteLine($"Bang on the answer was {numberTarget}.");
    }
  }
  else
  {
    Console.WriteLine("You didn't enter a valid number, retry.");
  }
}
while ( numberUser != numberTarget );
Console.WriteLine("Press a key to exit.");
Console.ReadKey();
```

Answer (score -1):

In your while loop, you forgot to make another ReadLine.

```
while (guess != value) //this stands for not equals to 
        {
            if (value > guess)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("too high");
                guess = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            }
            else if (value < guess)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("too low");
                guess = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            }
            else if (value == guess)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("bang on the answer was" + value);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("errrrrrrrrr");
            }
        }
```

Comment: If you're going to do it this way, it should be a `do...while` instead of a `while`.